# probability - paper, scissors, stone, who pay the bill for the dinner

Tags: probability

Tonight, I had dinner with my family and we played the game of "rock paper scissors" to determine which group should pay the bill.  First round everyone played, and the losers stayed and played the next round, unit the final single loser.

There are 2 groups,  Group A, living in apartment A, with 2 people and Group B, living in apartment B, with 3 people.  Everyone played the game in the beginning.  If the one whose lost the game was in Group A, Group A should pay the bill, and vice versa.

Questions:  a. What is the probability that Group B should pay the bill?
            b. the steps in getting the answer.

This is a high school level math quiz. My brother, who is a Ph.D in Chemistry, had different opinion than me on how to arrive at the result.

Anyone can help to confirm?

Regards
Alex Chu

Comment: What if one person from group B wins a game and loses a game in round 1? Does he lose?

Comment: What does "everyone played the game in the beginning" mean? I know how rock-paper-scissors works when played by _two_ people, but how do 5 people play it?

Comment: Can you please share your opinion, your brother's opinion, and the steps in getting the answer for each one of you two?

Comment: You need to try the: Rock Paper Scissor Lizard Spock, to minimize the possibility of too many ties. :D

Comment: BTW, assuming uniform probability (which is most certainly the case in RPS), you can simply ask yourself the equivalent question - what is the probability that a person chosen at random belongs in group B? (to which the answer is obviously $\frac35$).

Comment: After each round, the loser(s) stays in the game.  The one(s) who wins leaves the game.   For example, round 1,  "Rock, Rock, Scissors, Scissors, Scissors", the last 3 people stay in the game for next round, then say, "Rock, Paper, Rock", the remaining 1st and 3rd persons stay in the game, etc, until the final loser was determined.  If say, in round n, 4 people, the result is "Rock, Rock, Scissors, Paper", no loser, so the 4 people play again.

Comment: @ barak manos, I have the same reasoning and answer as you.  But my brother said my reasoning was not correct, and the probability of each type of combination of win/lose of each one in each group of the 2 groups with different number of people, should be considered, despite that he still could not come up with a solution.   So I wonder if anyone can confirm the reasoning of @barak manos is the correct one, which seems to be not rigorous enough to one who may challenge such simple reasoning.

Comment: @ barak manos.  My brother says each round, some people will leave the game, so each next round the number of players will be different.  He told me he list out all the possible outcomes for group of 1 vs group of 2, and group of 1 vs group of 3.  His conclusion is that for any 2 groups, 1st group has one people, 2nd group has N people, the probability of group A pays is 1/2 and that of group B pays is also 1/2.  Then he use induction to conclude that for 2 groups of group A of N1 vs group B of N2,  the probability of group B pays, still 1/2, regardless of group N1 and N2.

Comment: @ barak manos.  His other reasoning "consider in opposite direction . win or lose should have the same probability for both groups ( by symmetry)".   He insists on the answer of 1/2, despite I told him his steps obviously wrong, and against all instincts.

Comment: @ barak manos, my brother has a new answer: " the probability for the group with less people should be higher to pay for the dinner. ".   I would say the opposite.

Comment: Still I don't understand who stays in the game when you have say 2 rocks, 2 papers and one scissors

Comment: @ N74 -   if 2 rocks, 2 papers and one scissors, no one wins and all stay in the game and play the next round, until someone wins and leaves the game.

Comment: @ barak manos,  I finally convinced my brother to accept your answer.  On the other hand, if we add another rule, it will be post-grad level:   say we play until the last 2 losers.  If both losers in same group, then that group pays.  If one loser in on group and the other loser in the other group, the two group split the bill.  Questions: a) probability of group A of two pays, and b) probability of group B of three pays, and c) probability that the two groups split the bill.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is my understanding of the problem (Please note the last time I solved a probability question was in high school - I am just using my logic)

Lets name "n" the total number of players in a current game.
In total, there is n^3 possible combinations.
Now if there is only 2 state present in a game (ex: 2 rocks, 3 papers), hence no draw, the combination is n^2

So the probability of someone going out is P = (n^2)/(n^3)  <=> P = 1/n

So the probability of someone winning the 4 rounds will be (1/5)*(1/4)*(1/3)*(1/2)

Pwinning =  0.00833333

Because there is 2 persons in Team A and 3 in team B

Probability of team A winning is (2/5)x0.0083333

Probability of team B winning is (3/5)x0.0083333

Again, I am not sure about my answer. If someone more experienced can confirm/negate it would be perfect :)

Comment: Obviously wrong, since P(Team A Pays the Dinner) + P(Team B Pays the Dinner) = One always; since no case of no team pays, and no case of both team pays. Either Team A pays or Team B pays, not both, and one Team must pay (otherwise the restaurant owner will shoot all people dead).  This is the basic assumption of probability theory.

Comment: yes your right. I don't know how i missed this :S